# Using urllib2 via proxy

Tags: python, http, proxy, urllib2

I am trying to use `urllib2` through a proxy; however, after trying just about every variation of passing my verification details using `urllib2`, I either get a request that hangs forever and returns nothing or I get `407 Errors`. I can connect to the web fine using my browser which connects to a prox-pac and redirects accordingly; however, I can't seem to do anything via the command line `curl`, `wget`, `urllib2` etc. even if I use the proxies that the prox-pac redirects to. I tried setting my proxy to all of the proxies from the pac-file using `urllib2`, none of which work.

My current script looks like this:

```
import urllib2 as url

proxy = url.ProxyHandler({'http': 'username:password@my.proxy:8080'})
auth = url.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
opener = url.build_opener(proxy, auth, url.HTTPHandler)
url.install_opener(opener)
url.urlopen("http://www.google.com/")
```

which throws `HTTP Error 407: Proxy Authentication Required` and I also tried:

```
import urllib2 as url

handlePass = url.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
handlePass.add_password(None, "http://my.proxy:8080", "username", "password")
auth_handler = url.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(handlePass)
opener = url.build_opener(auth_handler)
url.install_opener(opener)
url.urlopen("http://www.google.com")
```

which hangs like `curl` or `wget` timing out.

What do I need to do to diagnose the problem? How is it possible that I can connect via my browser but not from the command line on the same computer using what would appear to be the same proxy and credentials?

Might it be something to do with the router? if so, how can it distinguish between browser `HTTP` requests and command line `HTTP` requests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frustrations like this are what drove me to use [Requests](http://python-requests.org). If you're doing significant amounts of work with urllib2, you really ought to check it out. For example, to do what you wish to do using Requests, you could write:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPProxyAuth

proxy = {'http': 'http://my.proxy:8080'}
auth = HTTPProxyAuth('username', 'password')
r = requests.get('http://wwww.google.com/', proxies=proxy, auth=auth)
print r.text
```

Or you could wrap it in a Session object and every request will automatically use the proxy information (plus it will store & handle cookies automatically!):

```
s = requests.Session(proxies=proxy, auth=auth)
r = s.get('http://www.google.com/')
print r.text
```