# Corporate Proxy works in C# but not in Python

Tags: c#, python, proxy

I am behind a corporate proxy and I am trying to download page sources using Python. A colleague tried writing a similar program in C# and it worked, but my Python code doesn't work, though we provided the same credentials. Below is the C# code:

```
class Program 
    { 
        static void Main(string[] args) 
        { 
            var netCred = new NetworkCredential { UserName = "asdf", Password = "pass", Domain = "Africa" }; 
            var webProxy = new WebProxy("corp_proxy:8080", true);   

            webProxy.Credentials = netCred; 

            using (WebClient client = new WebClient() { Proxy = webProxy }) 
            using (Stream data = client.OpenRead(@"http://www.google.com <http://www.google.com/> ")) 
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data)) 
            { 
                client.Proxy = webProxy; 
                string s = reader.ReadToEnd(); 
                Console.WriteLine(s); 
            } 

            Console.ReadLine(); 
        } 
    }
```

Below is the Python code,

```
import urllib2

proxy_user = "Africa\\asdf"
proxy_password = "pass"
proxy_port = "8080"
proxy_url = "corp_proxy"

def proxy_test():

  proxy_tot = 'http://' + proxy_user + ':' + proxy_password + '@' + proxy_url + ':' + proxy_port
  proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({"http":proxy_tot})
  auth = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
  opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy, auth, urllib2.HTTPHandler)
  urllib2.install_opener(opener)
  x = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com')
  print x.read()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  proxy_test()
```

The error output is

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\test.py", line 21, in <module>
    proxy_test()
  File ".\test.py", line 17, in proxy_test
    x = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com')
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 407: Proxy Authentication Required
```

Then I tried using https, and the error I received is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\test.py", line 21, in <module>
    proxy_test()
  File ".\test.py", line 17, in proxy_test
    x = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com')
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\urllib2.py", line 722, in <lambda>
    meth(r, proxy, type))
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\urllib2.py", line 751, in proxy_open
    return self.parent.open(req, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\urllib2.py", line 1222, in https_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\urllib2.py", line 1184, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 1] _ssl.c:510: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23
_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol>
```

What is wrong in the Python code?

Comment: is the proxy https and not http? Can you provide the error output? Take a look at [this](http://www.wkoorts.com/wkblog/2008/10/27/python-proxy-client-connections-requiring-authentication-using-urllib2-proxyhandler/)

Comment: I used the code on the website and it still doesn't work...

Comment: @dev247 any other ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the proxy uses basic authentication, not digest or NTLM?

Comment: I think cynic is on the right track.  I bet the proxy server uses NTLM.  From the [MS documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkcredential(v=vs.110).aspx): "The NetworkCredential class is a base class that supplies credentials in password-based authentication schemes such as basic, digest, **NTLM**, and Kerberos."

Comment: By the way, you didn't show us the C# code. It could shed light on the difference.

Answer (score 2):

Since your proxy uses NTLM authentication, you have to use a compatible `AuthHandler`, like [`ProxyNtlmAuthHandler`](https://code.google.com/p/python-ntlm/).

Comment: Where did you see that proxy is using NTLM authentication? Domain info in `NetworkCredential` will be used only IF requested, which would not be the case on a basic or digest authentication.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't absolutely require the use of urllib2, requests might make it easier.

```
import requests

proxy_user = "Africa\\asdf"
proxy_password = "pass"
proxy_url = "http://corp_proxy:8080"

def proxy_test():
    proxy = {'http': proxy_url}
    auth = HTTPProxyAuth(proxy_user, proxy_password)
    r = requests.get('http://www.google.com/', proxies=proxy, auth=auth)
    print r.text

if __name__ == "__main__":
    proxy_test()
```

This [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928385/using-urllib2-via-proxy) post will cover this, and the use of [requests.Session](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects) objects, [Here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#proxies) is more information on proxies with the requests lib. Hopefully this is a bit easier on you.

Comment: Finally I got a non-error output. What I got is the HTML source of my company saying "your credentials couldn't be authenticated." I tried putting no username and no password, and the output is still the same. I have no problem authenticating on my colleague's C# code, though. Also, unfortunately none of the people in my company know Python.. so they couldn't be much of a help

Comment: So the script is failing to authenticate to your corporate or the remotely proxied location? or are they the same, where you are trying to connect to the corporate proxy for outside internet?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a HTTP (not HTTPS) proxy.

The proxy's answer indicate that could not validate your authentication:
`HTTP Error 407: Proxy Authentication Required`.

You can try the following code. You can check the proxy realm on the Proxy-Authentication header returned by the proxy server.

```
proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': 'http://proxy.company.local:3128/'})
proxy_auth_handler = urllib2.ProxyBasicAuthHandler()
proxy_auth_handler.add_password('Company Proxy Realm', 'proxy.company.local', 'username', 'password')

opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_handler, proxy_auth_handler)
opener.open('http://www.google.com')
opener.open('https://www.google.com')
```

Comment: what do you mean by the "Proxy-Authentication header returned by the proxy server."?

Comment: The realm set in `proxy_auth_handler.add_password()` is informed in this header. You can check it using the command `curl -D - -o /dev/null -x http://proxy.company.local:8000 http://www.google.com`

Comment: That header will be set in the HTTP response returned by proxy.

Comment: I got "urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed>"

Comment: Appears to have any issue with hostname set in proxy address or URL. Change proxy to IP address and try again.

Comment: So did you manage to get it to work? The main information here is to confirm the authentication method used by proxy, which you can check with the curl command above in `Proxy-Authenticate` header: `curl --silent -v -x http://proxy.company.local:8080 http://www.google.com.br >/dev/null 2>&1 | grep Proxy-Authenticate`